# Re-initialization of iterator of ArrayList does not work

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

Given the following :

```
    // get the list of the players , in order to start the game 
    ArrayList<String> players = this.m_maze.getPlayers();
    // human side 
    String humanPlayer = iterator.next();
    String computerPlayer = null;
    // define iterator for the players 

    Iterator<String> iterator = players.iterator();     
    boolean humanSide = true ,computerSide = false;    // assume the human player is starting the game 


    // controller - start a game between the players , at least two players are playing 

    while (this.m_rounds > 0)  
    {

        if (humanSide == false && computerSide == true) // then this is the turn of the human side 
        {
            if (iterator.hasNext() == false)
            {
                // reinitialize the iterator
                Iterator<String> iterator = players.iterator();

            }
            while (iterator.hasNext())


                        // more code
```

I try to reuse the iterator but I get a "Duplicate local variable iterator" compilation error. How can I reuse that iterator ? 
Thanks ,Ron

**EDIT :**

```
            if (iterator.hasNext() == false)
            {
                // reinitialize the iterator
                iterator = players.iterator();

            }
            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {
                computerPlayer = iterator.next();

                // computer decides what would be his next move , between 1 - 3
```

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to do is iterate cyclically. Have you considered actually using a cyclical data structure?

Comment: This is a very good idea , I'll take that into consideration , thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't re-declare the variable; just assign it.

```
if (iterator.hasNext() == false) {
    iterator = players.iterator();
}
```

You should be careful about nested loop behavior.  Is your real intent to have have the following block

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) { ... }
```

actually check for this condition?

```
while (iterator.hasNext() && (this.m_rounds > 0)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have put `Iterator<String> iterator = players.iterator();` in your loop.

So each time it tries to create variable with name `iterator`.

Just put it's declaration out of the loop... like

```
 Iterator<String> iterator;     //here ****
 while (this.m_rounds > 0)  
   {

    if (humanSide == false && computerSide == true) // then this is the turn of the human side 
    {
        if (iterator.hasNext() == false)
        {
            // reinitialize the iterator
            iterator = players.iterator();

        }
        while (iterator.hasNext())
```

Comment: This will throw a `NullPointerException` since `iterator` is not assigned a value prior to `hasNext()`'s invocation.

Comment: @cheeken if it's the case then it will already be throwing exception bcoz according to his code he hasn't assigned any value to iterator before hasNext()

Answer (score 1):

I think google guava has pretty much what you want with [`Iterators#cycle`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#cycle%28java.lang.Iterable%29).

Use it like this:

```
    Iterator<String> iterator = Iterators.cycle(players.iterator());
```

...and you will never run out of players.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use iterators like this, it can mess things up, just do it the old way, I mean using the famous Mr. Iterator "i". Moreover the code would look more sensible.

```
    while(m_rounds > 0){

        if(i == players.size()) {
            i = 0;
        }

        currentPlayer = players.get(i);

        //Do what you want to do with the current player...

        ...

        //Next
        i++;


    }
```

A small suggestion, do you really need both the flags, i mean the humanSide and computerSide? Won't using just one suffice? Your if-else block would look a lot more simpler and clear:

```
if(humanSide) {

   //Hope this move wouldn't crush your logic.

} else {

  //Algorithm based awesome move.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay just remove the  `Iterator<String>` , meaning is , when reusing that iterator just write : `iterator = players.iterator();`

Thank you all !!